# Solution to Cauchy Euler ODE on an Interval Containing $0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am wondering if there are any cases where the homogeneous Cauchy-Euler differential equation, $$ax^2 y'' + bxy' + cy = 0,$$ has a non-trivial solution on an interval containing $x = 0$. If so, what are the conditions on $a,b$ and $c$? I have seen solutions to this kind of equation strictly when $x>0$, and strictly when $x<0$, but not when $x = 0$ since the equation is singular.

The reason I am asking this is that I am considering an inhomogeneous Cauchy Euler  boundary value problem over an interval containing zero, and would like to know whether or not the only solution to the inhomogeneous problem is the trivial solution.

Comment: With charactristic equation this DE has solution if $ar^2+(b-1)r+c=0$ has a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation has solutions of the form $x^r$ if $r$ is a solution of the quadratic equation
$$
a\,r\,(r-1)+b\,r+c=0.
$$
If one of its roots is non negative, there will be solutions defined on $(-\infty,\infty)$. For instance, the general solution of 
$$
x^2\,y''-2\,x\,y'+2\,y=0
$$
is
$$
y=C_1\,x+C_2\,x^2.
$$